# Java streams to remove element if result is null

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java streams and I have a quick question.

I have a list with objects.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

And a second List with different Objects.

```
List<Object2> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Basically I have a filter method to check if some conditions are met.

If condition is true:

add object to list

If method returns null or condition is false:

filter object out.

This what I have tried but I would like to know whats should be best practice for this kind of filtration.

```
List<Objet> res = list.stream().filter(x -> x.status == Status.OLD).filter(x -> {
 (findRelevantObject(x, list2)))
  return x != null
})
.collect(Collectors.toList));
```

```
private Object findRelevantObject(Object x, List<list2> list2) {
       boolean isExist = list2().stream().filter(m -> m.getId() == x.getId()).allMatch(m -> m.isToChangeNum() == 1);

return isExist ? x : null;
}
```

Comment: The code as presented here doesn't compile.  `List<list2>` probably was intended to be `List<Object2>`, `list2().stream()` was probably supposed to be `list2.stream()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly remove elements from a Java Stream. Streams are meant to be processed in a pipeline-like manner. The way to achieve this effect is to filter out null values and create a new stream.

```
List<String> myList = List.of("Hello", null, "World", "!", null);

// Filter out null elements and collect into a new list
List<String> filteredList = myList.stream()
                                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)  
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());


System.out.println(filteredList); // Output: [Hello, World, !]
//this line filters out non-null values =>.filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `groupingBy`, `reducing` and `filter` without external functions:

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<Integer, Boolean> idExistMap = list2.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(A::getId, reducing(true, obj -> obj.isToChangeNum() == 1, (a, b) -> a && b)));
    
List<A> res = list.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.status == Status.OLD)
    .filter(x -> idExistMap.getOrDefault(x.getId(), false))
    .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: You can remove a step by skipping the `Optional` and just using a stream: `.flatMap(x -> idExistMap.getOrDefault(x.getId(), false) ? Stream.of(x) : Stream.of())`. Also, `filter` would seem to be simpler and more idiomatic than the `map/flatMap`: `.filter(x -> idExistMap.containsKey(x.getId()))`.